# How downcasting takes place by using the 'final' keyword in Java

Tags: java, final

Consider:

```java
class UnderstandingConversion {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        int a=10, b=20;

        byte c = (a>b) ? 40 : 50;

        System.out.println(c);
        // output : lossy conversion error
    }
}
```

This code is giving an error as 'lossy conversion' which I understand, but if I use the `final` keyword in the code as shown below, it is working fine.

```java
class UnderstandingConversion {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        final int a=10, b=20;

        byte c = (a>b)? 40 : 50;

        System.out.println(c);
        // Output: 50

    }
}
```

How is `final` working here and how does downcasting take place?

Comment: Presumably final gives the compiler enough information to deduce the conversion is actually fine.

Comment: Referring to A final variable with a constant value is a constant expression, making the whole ternary expression a constant expression. And a constant expression of type int can be assigned to a variable of type byte if the constant value is in the range of a byte

Comment: Hint: `byte c = (a>b) ? 40 : (byte)50;` or `byte c = (a>b) ? (byte)40 : 50;` will work fine even without making `a`, `b` final.

Comment: @Pshemo yes, that is proper typecasting but how it is working by using final

Comment: I suppose for the "final" case, compiler optimizes to `byte c = 50`, which seems legit. For the non-final case, compiler is perhaps not so clever to see both cases of the `?` are properly convertable to `byte`

Comment: `final` lets compiler be sure that values of `a` and `b` will not change. With that it knows that `(a>b)? 40 : 50;` will always be `(10>20)? 40 : 50;` which is equivalent of `(false)? 40 : 50;` which in turn is equivalent of `50`. So when you use `final` compiler to save us time of evaluating `(10>20)? 40 : 50;` each time `main` method is called it replaces it with result `50` (since it will never change). This means you end up with `byte c = (a>b)? 40 : 50;` (don't want to post it as answer since proper answer would require quoting specification and I don't have time now to search through it)

Comment: The non-final version is seen as `(condition) ? someInt : someInt` which leads compiler to see `byte c = (a>b)? 40 : 50;` is `byte c = someInt;` which is why it gives you error. One of solution could be casting one of results to `byte` like `byte c = (a>b) ? 40 : (byte)50;` which forces other result to also be seen as `byte` (again, will need to find it in specification).

Comment: @Pshemo I don't think you're far from the explanation but I don't understand something though. Whether the expression is true or false, c will always be either 40 or 50 and in both cases, the conversion is not lossy. So I would still expect the compiler not to cry about this... But even if the compiler was optimizing the bytecode somehow, why would casting the 40 or 50 to byte (as you shown) would make it work again?

Comment: I can't edit my previous comments but "*This means you end up with byte `c = (a>b)? 40 : 50;`*" should be: "*This means you end up with `byte c = 50;`*".

Comment: @MatteoNNZ Yes, compiler could be smarter here, but apparently there is not much gain here (such cases are probably too rare) so there was no *need* to improve it for such scenario. 
Regarding "..why would casting the 40 or 50 to byte (as you shown) would make it work again?" because compiler must ensure that both results are of the same type and in this case it doesn't *widen* `byte to int`, but is designed to *narrow* types. So `byte c = (a>b) ? (byte)40 : 50;` forces `50` (which is `int`) to be treated as `byte` (narrows int to byte because other value was byte).

Comment: @MatteoNNZ Found relevant part of specification (for Java 7): https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.25 "Otherwise, if the *second and third operands* have types that are convertible (§5.1.8) to numeric types, (...) If one of the operands is of type T ***where T is `byte`, `short`, or `char`***, and the other operand is a constant expression (§15.28) of type `int` whose value is representable in type T, ***then the type of the conditional expression is T.***". So `(a>b) ? (byte)40 : 50;` makes *result* of such conditional operator `byte`.

Comment: @MatteoNNZ But only if `int` is constant expression. So "trick" with casting may work for `(a>b) ? (byte)40 : 50;` bit will NOT work for `(a>b) ? (byte)40 : intD;` (assuming `intD` is not considered as *constant expression*) - here result of conditional (ternary) operator will be `int`.

Answer (score 33):

The [JLS](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/jls8.pdf) has [predefined rules](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.2) for assignment conversion.

If the expression is a constant expression ([§15.28](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.28)) of type byte, short, char, or int:

> A narrowing primitive conversion may be used if the type of the
> variable is byte, short, or char, and the value of the constant
> expression is representable in the type of the variable.

The definition of constant expression:

> - Literals of primitive type and literals of type String
> - Simple names ([§6.5.6.1](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-6.html#jls-6.5.6.1)) that refer to constant variables ([§4.12.4](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.12.4)).
> - The relational operators <, <=, >, and >= (but not instanceof) ([§15.20](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.20))

The [§4.12.4](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.12.4) defines what final variable is

> A variable of primitive type or type String, that is final and
> initialized with a compile-time constant expression ([§15.28](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.28)), is
> called a constant variable.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis thank you for pointing out, added the relational operators

Comment: Sorry, but I do not see how that explains the behavior. `(a>b)? 40 : 50` is neither *"[a] literal of primitive type"* nor *"[a] literal of type String"* nor *"[a] [s]imple name"* nor *"[a] relational operator <, <=, >, [or] >"*.

Comment: @Heinzi The quote should also include "A constant expression is an expression denoting a value of primitive type or a String that does not complete abruptly and is composed using only the following:" and list the "The ternary conditional operator `? :`" as one of the allowed constructs.

Answer (score 25):

The compiler is 100% confident that a>b will resolve to false - therefore it takes only the `else` branch of the ternary operator into account - and the compiler knows that the constant 50 fits the range of `byte` and therefore it is not cast, but it is defined as byte at compile time.

To prove that the compiler is taking into the account only the `else` value, you can do this:

```
    final int a=10, b=20;
    byte c = (a>b) ? 1234 : 50;
```

which will compile just fine, but doing

```
final int a=10, b=20;
byte c = (a>b) ? 50 : 1234;
```

will yield an error. 1234 is out of range of byte, but yet it is perfectly fine in the first example as this branch is ignored.

I am sure that someone with better expertise can point to the JLS paragraph explaining that is happening here.

**Observation update**

It turns out, that if we would inspect the bytecode, we would most probably see that `a` and `b` are replaced with constant values (and maybe there is not a branch at all). I have debugged that code and changed the A value to 10000 before the ternary operator (using a debugger), but yet execution still yields c=50, despite A>B being true now.

It is a fun fact to know ;) thanks for rising an issue so I could learn a new thing

Comment: "and the compiler knows that the constant 50 fits the range of byte". Yes, but so would 40, right?

Comment: Sure, but again 40 is ignored - this is why non byte values are passed trough compilation.

Comment: @EricDuminil The language designers probably didn't bother checking both branches for constant expressions when the condition is non-constant.

Comment: @xehpuk when the condition **is constant**. And that is correct.

Comment: ^ This should be the accepted answer! Congrats for providing such of a simple explanation that fully addresses the issue.

Comment: @PanagiotisBougioukos it is included already in the answer

Comment: This answer does not answer the question at all, it is answering a different question (“why does the value in the else branch not matter when using final variables?”).

Answer (score 2):

If you decompile the code that uses `final`, and concentrating only in the assignments of `a`, `b` and `c`, you get:

```
   L0
    LINENUMBER 4 L0
    BIPUSH 10
    ISTORE 1
   L1
    BIPUSH 20
    ISTORE 2
   L2
    LINENUMBER 5 L2
    BIPUSH 50
    ISTORE 3
```

So, as can be seen, the element the bytecode assigns to `c` is `50`, which is a constant byte value.